# Как реализовать свой DisplayFormatAttribute атрибут?

Tags: c#

Есть следующий класс

```
public class Request
{
    public int Downtime {get;set;}
}
```

свойство `Downtime` содержит кол-во минут. Подскажите как реализовать *свой* атрибут по аналогии с `DisplayFormat`, т.е. что бы для свойства можно было указать какие то свойства, а внутри будет скрыта некоторая логика, например: `$"{downtime/60}:{downtime%60}"`).

Мне это необходимо для создания универсального метода выгрузки результата запроса в excel. Заготовка метода выглядит так:

```
public void PrintRows<T>(ExcelWorksheet sheet, IEnumerable<T> rows, bool printTitle = false) where T: class
{
    var columns = (from property in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                   let attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute
                   let format = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as DisplayFormatAttribute
                   where attribute != null
                   orderby attribute.Order
                   select new
                   {
                       Property = property,
                       Order = attribute.Order,
                       Name = attribute.Name,
                       Format = format?.DataFormatString ?? string.Empty
                   });
    var rowNumber = 1;

    if (printTitle)
    {
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowNumber, column.Order].Value = column.Name;
        }
        rowNumber++;
    }

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var value = column.Property.GetValue(row, null);
            sheet.Cells[rowNumber, column.Order].Value = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(column.Format))
            {
                sheet.Cells[rowNumber, column.Order].Style.Numberformat.Format = column.Format;
            }
        }
        rowNumber++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно такой пример подойдет вам или натолкнет на мысль в нужном направлении.

Заведем базовый атрибут для кастомного форматирования:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)] // Можно применять только к свойствам
public abstract class CustomFormatAttribute : Attribute
{
    public abstract string Format(object value);
}
```

Пара реализаций для примера:

```
public class TimeFormatAttribute : CustomFormatAttribute
{
    public override string Format(object value)
    {
        var time = (int)value;
        return $"{time / 60 :00}:{time % 60 :00}";
    }
}

public class MoneyFormatAttribute : CustomFormatAttribute
{
    public override string Format(object value)
    {
        var money = (decimal)value;
        return $"{value} руб.";
    }
}
```

Класс элемента:

```
class Item
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [TimeFormat]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [MoneyFormat]
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
}
```

Пусть теперь у нас имеется некая коллекция таких элементов:

```
var items = new[]
{
    new Item { Number = 10, Time = 300, Money = 299.95M },
    new Item { Number = 20, Time = 250, Money = 287.95M },
    new Item { Number = 30, Time = 200, Money = 275.95M },
    new Item { Number = 40, Time = 150, Money = 263.95M },
    new Item { Number = 50, Time = 100, Money = 251.95M }
};
```

Применяем кастомное форматирование:

```
var props = typeof(Item).GetProperties();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(item);
        var attribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute<CustomFormatAttribute>();
        Console.WriteLine(attribute?.Format(value) ?? value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```